# ajax is successful but PHP file can't run

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

In my ajax I can see the console message, which means my ajax is successful to send data to php file, but  in php file it seams no echo or function runs.(both files are at same folder)

index.php
Script:

```
     function kk(){  
      $(document).ready(function(){
       var id = document.getElementById('auto').value;
       var datastring = 'id1=' + id;      
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getHint2.php",
            data: datastring,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
              console.log(" ajax success");
            // echo what the server sent back
           }
        });
    });
   }
```

getHint2.php file:

```
 echo "this is from php file!";
   if(isset($_POST['id1']))
   {
       echo "hello " . $_POST['id1'];
   };
```

HTML:
and kk is the JS function which is in above.

```
 <div class="caret">
            <form>
                <input type="text" value="97121243" id="auto">
            </form>           
   </div>
        <input type="button" value="click" onclick="kk();"/>
```

Comment: Can you run your PHP file by itself?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard, yes php file runs by itself.

Comment: try `console.log(data);`

Comment: @George Garchagudashvili, I tried it and  alert box, gives me a weird result. It is  like this "<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs.. "

Comment: Maybe run it with Firebug Net dump or similar to watch the communication between your JS and server. Or test your PHP  by a simple HTML form and POST data.

Comment: @rantanplan, in firebug status of post gitHint2 is 200 ok.

Comment: what shows console.log(id)? - maybe its just empty

Comment: We need to see some of the HTML in index.php

Comment: @rantanplan condole.log(id) shows : id1= 97121243.

Comment: This works just fine for me. If you console.log(data); you can see the php reply. I'm running the same source code to what you posted.

Comment: This works for me too, with the specified HTML and JS.  I'm using jQuery 1.11.2 linked from the jQuery CDN.  @Amir, see if you can get just this barebones code to run (without anything else you might have in the JS page or PHP processor).

Comment: I'm linking to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js and all is fine, not one error so the issue cannot be in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `console.log(id)` right before the actual ajax call.  It is possible that it's not sending the value that you think it's sending.

Also, since you're using jQuery, you can simply do:

```
var id = $('#auto').val();
```

As a side note, I'd highly recommend that you look into the `.submit` callback and `.serialize` function for designing and processing forms with AJAX.  For example, I would implement it like this:

```
<div class="caret">
    <form id = "myForm">
        <input type="text" name="id1" value="97121243" id="auto">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>           
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myForm").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            // Serialize the form data
            var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({  
              type: "POST",  
              url: "getHint2.php",  
              data: serializedData,
              cache: false,
            }).done(function(data) {      
              console.log(data);
            // echo what the server sent back
           });
        });
    });

</script>
```

A few comments:

1. I used the `<button>` element instead of the `<input>` element.  `<button>` is a newer, more flexible way of implementing buttons
2. I set the button to `type=submit` and place it inside the `<form>`, so I don't need to manually link the clicking of the button to the ajax submission.  It just happens when the form gets submitted!
3. By using `.serialize()`, I don't need to explicitly specify each and every form variable that I want to send - all I need to do is give each control an appropriate `name` attribute!  This will make your code easier to maintain down the road.
4. I use `.done(function(data) {` instead of `success`.  Note that `success` is [deprecated as of jQuery 1.8](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: I already tried it, and after this when I run console.log(id), I get undefined.

Comment: Could you post the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the semicolon after the first echo in your php file.

Comment: That is true, but still same problem exist.

Comment: When I run your code I can see both echos in the response.

Answer (score 0):

For your data string, try:

```
var datastring = {id1: id};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax debugging can be a strange beast. You are essentially debugging two scripts at the same time, only one of which you can see at runtime (the javascript). There are a handful of things that may help you:

set a pending and fail function for your request.

The pending function should display some kind of visual representation that the callback for success or fail has not yet fired. It should be removed by both the success and fail callback. Something like a spinner is pretty common.

The fail function should log information to the console for you to review about the request for debugging while you are working out the bugs, and in production may either be removed or display some kind of failure message for the end user that does not impart server details.

This will tell you whether or not the script believes the request to be successful. jQuery will determine this based on a few factors:

1. A response was recieved from the server.
2. The response matches the expected Accept headers passed with the request (if you did not define them, jQuery will use it's defaults). An easy way to handle this is to always pass your data back in a common format like JSON, and set the accept header to only accept json, so if you get back an error message or other response it will fail correctly regardless of output.
3. A valid response code header is passed. You can set the [response header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) for success on the php side using `http_response_code(200)`, which should be passed at some point prior to echoing page content if the request is valid.

Debugging involves a couple of clues, assuming you have all of these covered. You can check for the response header in Firebug or another browser inspector.

One thing I like to do is set a session token on the php side, which you can then check for by var_dumping the $_SESSION, which should show up if the ajax request is actually hitting the server. If this turns up and you are still getting a fail response, you just need to correct the response data and/or header, as php is working but not passing the request back correctly.

If you are simply trying to get a successful response, just have php print exactly what you passed it and `console.log()` that in your success function. If you want more detailed info about the response, use `console.dir()` instead, which is essentially `var_dump()` for javascript.